# R create virtual class for "Matrix" and NULL

Tags: r, r-s4

I am quite new for R S4 classes. I am trying to define a virtual class that allow NULL and "Matrix" from the Matrix package(http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/).
I try to use "setClassUnion" with the following code:

```
library(Matrix)
setClassUnion("MatrixOrNULL", c("Matrix", "NULL"))
```

I hope the new virtual class "MatrixOrNULL" would allow NULL and all actual classes in package "Matrix". However, when I try to check whether an instance is "MatrixOrNULL", I got some strange answers like the following:

```
# Define a Matrix, a data frame and a string
mt <- Matrix(matrix(1:6, 2, 3))
df <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=6:10)
st <- "abc"

# Check whether it is a MatrixOrNULL
is(NULL, "MatrixOrNULL")         #  TRUE
is(mt, "MatrixOrNULL")           #  TRUE
is(df, "MatrixOrNULL")           #  TRUE
is(st, "MatrixOrNULL")           #  TRUE
```

I suppose the "data.frame" and "character" variables are not "MatrixOrNULL", but it returns "TRUE" me. (Actually everything I tried is a "MatrixOrNULL" object.)

Could anyone help me to figure out what's the problem of this virtual class?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.  The last two `is` statements result in FALSE.

Answer (score 2):

The actual class of a Matrix object (`class(mt)`) appears to be `'dgeMatrix'`

so this appears to do what you're after:
`setClassUnion("MatrixOrNULL", c("dgeMatrix", "NULL"))`

EDIT: I realize now that you wanted every class in the package.

Unfortunately, there appears to be no shared class between these objects. So there are a few ways:

1) you could simply check all the classes in the Matrix package, and refer to them explicitly in your class union: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/Matrix.pdf

2) If you want to know if it came from the Matrix package,
you could always check if the `attr(object,'package')` is equal to 'Matrix'. This seems more what you're after, because inheriting from every Matrix class sounds like there would be conflicts.